# ELUs activation function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, neural-network

I am trying to figure out what is "a" parameter in:
[image: ELUs equation image]
a is hyper-parameter to be tuned and a>= 0 is a constraint for ELUs

Here is the equation of Leaky ReLUs which uses 0.01 as an a parameter but has a bit different description of the parameter a:
[image: Leaky ReLUs equation image]

a is a <= 1 equivalent to:
[image: a for Leaky ReLUs]

As i have been searching through already written libraries i have found this equation of Leaky ReLUS:

```js
function LeakyReLU(x) {
    return (x < 0 ? 0 : 0.01 * x);
}

console.log(LeakyReLU(6))
```

from [Brain.js](https://github.com/BrainJS/brain.js/blob/master/src/neural-network.js)

By the given pattern i would go ahead and write a function like this:

```js
function ELUs(x) {
    return (x < 0 ? 0 : 0.01*(Math.exp(x)-1));
}

console.log(ELUs(6));
```

but i am unsure about the a parameter and it's value of 0.01.

Is this the given equation right?